# How to add subtitles a complete folder using ffmpeg in linux

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I need to batch subtitles with `ffmpeg` , the `srt` file has got the same name of the video file associated, for example : `file1.mkv` with `file1.srt`, ... `file8.mp4` with `file8.srt`

how can I perform a batch burn for subtitles ?

Comment: Did you find the command to burn a subtitle in a video file? Then we can easily tell you how to automate this for a complete folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir outputs
for f in *.mkv *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf subtitles="${f%.*}.srt" -c:a copy outputs/"$f"; done
```

See:

- [FFmpeg subtitles filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles)
- [Bash parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Comment: Thank you !! this helps me alot !